# Looking for files of certain extension using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

As an exercise, I decide to rewrite some code of mine to use lambda expression. The code should check if a given string is a path to a file with `.pdf` extension and then it should display all the files that meet this requirement. This so what I've already come up with:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(args[0]), path -> path.toFile()
                    .toString()
                    .endsWith(".pdf"))
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This code fails at one point: it also displays directories. Could you tell me why the following code fails to compile?

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(args[0]), path -> path.toFile()
                    .isFile()
                    .toString()
                    .endsWith(".pdf"))
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Why `path.toFile().toString()` when `path.toString()` would do the same?

Comment: @Andreas `path.toFile()` allows me to do `path.toFile().isFile` while `path.toString()` doesn't.

Comment: I was referring to the first code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code fails to compile because `isFile` returns a `boolean`. Once you have a `boolean`, file name is gone; even if you could convert it to `String`, matching its suffix to `".pdf"` would fail anyway.

You are testing two separate conditions, so you should test them in two separate checks:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(args[0]), path ->
    Files.isRegularFile(path) &&  path.toString().endsWith(".pdf")
).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that `path.toString().endsWith(...)` can be checked without converting `Path` to `File`.

Comment: Very clean and nice solution. +1 for nothing that path.endsWith can be checked without converting Path to File and then to String.

Comment: Sorry, `path.endsWith(".pdf")` is not the same as `path.toString().endsWith(".pdf")`. [`Path.endsWiths(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) calls [`Path.endsWiths(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.nio.file.Path-), which compares elements: *If the given path has N elements, and no root component, and this path has N or more elements, then this path ends with the given path if the last N elements of each path, starting at the element farthest from the root, are equal.*

Comment: @Andreas You are absolutely right! For some odd reason, Java API designers resist adding an API for getting a file extension from the path, creating silly problems like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler expects to have a `boolean` as second argument of

```
newDirectoryStream(Path dir, DirectoryStream.Filter<? super Path> filter)
```

Filter being a functional interface defined as :

```
boolean accept(T entry) throws IOException;
```

But here :

```
  .isFile()
  .toString()
```

a `String` is returned.

Make things in two times by combining two boolean expressions :

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(args[0]), path -> 
                                             Files.isRegularFile(path)
                                             && path.toString().endsWith(".pdf"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

In addition to Andreas comment about :
`path.toFile().toString().endsWith(".pdf"))`

that may be abbreviated by : `path.toString().endsWith(".pdf")`, you could also replace

`path.toFile().isFile()` by `Files.isRegularFile(path)`.
It allows to rely only on the `java.nio.file` API rather that mixing it with the `java.io.file` API.

Comment: That's even more clear. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Sorry, `path.endsWith(".pdf")` is not the same as `path.toString().endsWith(".pdf")`. [`Path.endsWiths(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) calls [`Path.endsWiths(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.nio.file.Path-), which compares elements: *If the given path has N elements, and no root component, and this path has N or more elements, then this path ends with the given path if the last N elements of each path, starting at the element farthest from the root, are equal.*

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the info. The overloaded method with the string is very misleading !

Comment: @davidxxx Really? [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) says: *Tests if this path ends with a `Path`, constructed by converting the given path string, in exactly the manner specified by the `endsWith(Path)` method. On UNIX for example, the path `foo/bar` ends with `foo/bar` and `bar`. **It does not end with `r`** or `/bar`.*

Comment: @Andreas Which is misleading is not the Javadoc that is clear but the `endsWith(String )` that some (I here) may imagine close to `String.endsWith(String)` behavior, while it is not the case. Personally, I would prefer a name as `endsWithPath(String)` to make the method name enough to understand the method intention.